# how to customize string return

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to customize a string which return from a mysql database?
I have a field which is image name and i would like to join it with my directory path.

```
SELECT * FROM brand
//row return.
id    image_name
1    image1.jpg

//i would like to have my return like
id    image_name
1    upload/image1.jpg
```

Comment: Is the directory path same for all files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is concatenation. Refer to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) for MySQL concat.

Basically, you could do

```
SELECT CONCAT('/path/to/dir/', filename) as `file_name`
FROM brand
```

which would return /path/to/dir/filename

Comment: It's good practice to give expressions such as `CONCAT()` an alias; otherwise it's hard to pull the column from the results by name (if it's not the only column).

Comment: be careful using / at the beginning though.  If referencing a UNIX environment directory after retrieving this value, it will start from root, not relative to the current directory... instead use ./ at the beginning to imply current working directory... this will make it work for Windows or *nix environments.

Answer (score 3):

Try this query:

```
SELECT id,
       CONCAT('upload/', image_name) AS `file_name`
FROM   band
```

Answer (score 1):

Use concat() function  to customize your string as you want.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/4317

`select id, concat('upload', image_name) from tbl;`

Here is source http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat